# two updates using the same CTE

Tags: sql-server

I have to "unremove" folders in an arborescence (thay have been flagged as removed, I change the value of the flag). Each folder can contain files or folders (which are stored in different tables). I have a CTE that defines all the folders that need to be updated.

```
 WITH arbre(id) AS(
     SELECT idDossier
     FROM portail_managers_dossier
     WHERE idDossier = @id
     UNION ALL
     SELECT d.idDossier
     FROM portail_managers_dossier AS d
     INNER JOIN arbre AS a
     ON a.id = d.idParent)
```

Then I have two UPDATE request, one for each table

```
 UPDATE portail_managers_dossier
 SET dtDateSuppr = NULL
 WHERE idDossier IN (SELECT id FROM arbre);


 UPDATE portail_managers_document
 SET dtDateSuppr = NULL
 WHERE idDossier IN (SELECT id FROM arbre);
```

My problem is : I don't know how to merge two UPDATE requests on different tables. The CTE only exists until the end of the request, so I have to define it twice. Is there any way to write all of the above code in a single request ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As you have discovered, CTE's will lose scope after the first update. But, instead of using a CTE, why not write the results of the query within the CTE to a temp table, and do your updates based on the contents temp table?

Comment: This was going to be my advice as well.

Comment: @Mike M. - I love CTE's but they don't solve all the world's problems, unfortunately :).

Comment: I've read that temporary tabled hurt performance and should be avoided when possible. But I'm afraid I am in one of those cases where they can't be avoided. :)

Comment: @Thibault - 'Hurting performance' is relative to what you are trying to accomplish. Yes, it would be nice if you didn't have to write rows to a temp table, but you've got a job to do, and a CTE in this case, won't do what you want.

Comment: @Thibault: In your case, a recursive CTE, being a part of `IN` predicate, would be spooled to a temp table (or a hash table) anyway.

Comment: So at the moment I'm creating the same temp table twice, which is awful. ^^ Thank you all for the answers

Answer (score 3):

You can *save* the list of **idDossier** into variable from cte before execute the updates.

```
-- declare table variable
declare @listOfIDs table (idDossier int);

-- select ids of two tables
;WITH arbre(id) AS
(
     SELECT idDossier
     FROM portail_managers_dossier
     WHERE idDossier = @id
     UNION ALL
     SELECT d.idDossier
     FROM portail_managers_dossier AS d
     INNER JOIN arbre AS a
     ON a.id = d.idParent
 )

-- saving ids
insert @listOfIDs(idDossier) select idDossier from arbre

-- execute twice updates
UPDATE portail_managers_dossier
SET dtDateSuppr = NULL
WHERE idDossier IN (SELECT idDossier FROM @listOfIDs);

UPDATE portail_managers_document
SET dtDateSuppr = NULL
WHERE idDossier IN (SELECT idDossier FROM @listOfIDs);
```